# Multiple applications on one domain

Tags: node.js, go, server

### SITUATION

Let's say I have a domain `example.com`. I want to write a main application using Node.js and some components using Golang.

### QUESTIONS

Is it possible to run `api.example.com/first` using **Node.js** and `api.example.com/second` using **Golang**?
Or is it possible to write run different applications on different subdomains?

- I'm not talking about executing Golang programmes through Node.js

Comment: Yes it is possible, you'll need something in between the requests and the apps (a reverse proxy) to send those two different request to the two different applications.

Comment: That is possible, but usually it is handled outside of your application code. Sample for Apache web server - https://opensource.com/article/18/3/configuring-multiple-web-sites-apache

Comment: easiest way I can think of is to setup nginx in front of everything and let nginx send /first to nodejs and /second to golang server

Comment: You should also consider using subdomains instead.

Answer (score 2):

Best way I can think of is to:

1. Setup a reverse proxy such as Nginx
2. Run it on port 80 and 443 (for HTTPS)
3. Run you applications on different ports and bind to loopback IP address (127.0.0.1 usually)
4. Define your reverse proxy routes in Nginx to match your applications

Check out this tutorial on how to do the previous: https://flaviocopes.com/go-nginx-reverse-proxy/